# Sine integral and Lebesgue integration

Tags: improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

It can be proved in a wide variety of ways that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^n\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\text{, }
\end{equation}
but that not necessarily mean that $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the context of Lebesgue integration. Neither the monotone convergence theorem nor the dominated convergence theorem seems to help proving this. Any idea?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty|\sin x|\frac{dx}x$ is divergent.

Comment: @AnginaSeng could you give a hint on why is that true?

Comment: The point is, you can find small $\delta>0$, such that (by periodicity) $\sin(x) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \in (2k\pi-\delta,2k\pi)$ (say $\delta = 10^{-10}$, whatever). Then, since everything is positive, you can bound it from below by such series: $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{2k\pi - \delta}^{2k\pi} \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta \frac{1}{4k\pi} = \infty$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formalizing Dominik's idea. Note that $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert-\frac{1}{2}$ is continuous and $\pi$-periodic, being $\lvert\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)\rvert-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}>0$ for every integer $k$. As long as the function is continuous, we can find some $\delta>0$ such that if $\lvert x-(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)\rvert<\delta$, then $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert>\frac{1}{2}$ for every integer $k$.
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
   \int_{0}^\infty\frac{\lvert\sin(x)\rvert}{x}\mathrm{d} x&\geq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi-\delta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi+\delta}\frac{\lvert\sin(x)\rvert}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\&\geq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi-\delta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi+\delta}\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi+\delta}\mathrm{d}x\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2}2\delta\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi+\delta}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2\delta}{\pi+2k\pi+2\delta}\\&\geq\frac{\delta}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{\delta}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}=\infty\text{, }
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
as the harmonic series diverges.

This shows that a function which is Riemann-integrable in the improper sense, may not be Lebesgue-Integrable.